# PHP Force Command Line Output

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a command-line PHP script that is meant to be used with file output, for example:

```
php script.php -arg > file.txt
```

Suppose I have an error/exception in this file. I can either leave it uncaught (with or without using `throw`), and it will output something ugly that I don't want to the command line, or I can catch it, and then any output will go to `file.txt`, and the user won't immediately see it.

Is there a way to force certainly output to go to the command line, without affecting what the rest of the script writes to the file?

Comment: Catch the exception and write the error message to [`stderr`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php). It will be displayed on the screen because you redirected only `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was not aware of these possibilities. If you post it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception in your code and write the error message to [`stderr`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

```
try {
    // code that throws exceptions here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Report the exception to stderr, to not interfere with the script output
    fputs(STDERR, $e->getMessage());
    // Continue the script as you think it's best (resume the processing or exit).
}
```

When the output is not redirected, the content that is sent to `stdout` and `stderr` come on screen mixed (in the order they are generated, of course) because both streams are associated to the terminal.

When you redirect to `file.txt` only the `stdout`, the content that is written to `stderr` (your error messages) is displayed on the terminal. You can also redirect `stderr` to the same file or to a different file:

```
# Redirect stderr to a different file (file.err)
php script.php -arg >file.txt 2>file.err

# Redirect stdout to a file (file.txt) and duplicate stderr to stdout
# (to send its output to file.txt too)
# The order of redirections is important here
php script.php -arg >file.txt 2>&1
```